# Intermittent crash during NSMutableAttributedString setup

Tags: objective-c, macos, xcode4

I've some code to setup an NSMutableAttributedString:

```
    NSMutableParagraphStyle *centred = [[NSMutableParagraphStyle alloc]init];
    [centred setAlignment:NSCenterTextAlignment];
    NSDictionary *attributes = [[NSDictionary alloc]initWithObjectsAndKeys:[NSFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica bold" size:12],NSFontAttributeName,
                                [NSColor whiteColor],NSForegroundColorAttributeName,
                                [NSColor clearColor], NSBackgroundColorAttributeName, 
                                centred, NSParagraphStyleAttributeName,
                                nil];
    NSMutableAttributedString* attribTitle = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc]initWithString:@"Foo"];
    [attribTitle setAttributes:attributes range:NSMakeRange(0, [[attribTitle string] length] - 1)];
```

It's been sitting in my app's -awakeFromNib method almost since I started the project with no problems but just today I've begun to get every other attempt at running the app in Xcode 4.3 crashing out with "Thread 1:EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x10)". It breaks on the final '...setAttributes...' line. At one point I tried using the method – initWithString:attributes: to initialise attribTitle and sure enough the crash (when it did) was on the alloc-init line.

I've tried clearing Xcode restarting but it still happens about every other build... If the app doesn't crash then the attrbibuted string appears as expected.

I'm wondering if I have a corrupted project file, but just in case I've done something daft, can anyone point out a mistake - presumably it's in the 'attributes' NSDictionary?

Thanks!

Todd.

Comment: What happens if you initialize the paragraph style like this: `NSMutableParagraphStyle *centred = [[NSParagraphStyle defaultParagraphStyle] mutableCopy];`?

Comment: The other problem might be the way you're naming your font. Try breaking that code out and test whether your font is nil.

Comment: For what it's worth, I tried your code in a working project, no crashes so far on OS X SDK 10.7. I tried logging the font, as is, as per Wienke's suggestion, with the following result: `"Helvetica-Bold 12.00 pt. P [] (0x7ff6734f3f40) fobj=0x7ff6736d0190, spc=3.33"` -- no problems there, either.

Comment: Thanks both of you! modocache, I get the same o/p as you - thanks for taking the time. Wienke, I tried your suggestions and the -defaultParagraphStyle does make a difference: now i'm getting a "[* count] unrecognised selector sent to instance..." where '*' can be NSURL or NSCFString. And although I have an NSArray in -awakeFromNib, it's not being 'count'ed... I'm using this code to format NSButton titles. If I remove it completely, the app seems to run time after time. Have I just got the initialisation of the var's in the wrong place?

Comment: I am starting to think it's Xcode: For a couple of days now, I keep getting the 'Validate Project Settings' warning. It's saying the compiler is set to GDB for the Test action. This is a project I started in 4.3 and haven't moved it anywhere....

Comment: Good grief: I've got two versions of Xcode installed, 4.2 and 4.3. It was left in when I upgraded to 10.7!! That would explain the project settings thing. I run multiple accounts (I like to make things deliberately difficult for myself) and I'll bet I opened the project in 4.2 a few times. I'll repost if a clean install doesn't work.

Comment: @Todd I have this same Validate Project Settings warning in a quite straightforward project, also mentioning GDB (wants to upgrade to LLDB each time). I comes up over and over again. That might be a bug in Xcode.

Answer (score 1):

Is this the code you run, of is it simplified? As it is, it looks Ok to me (I dare say). When it crashes only every other time, than that indicates some other circumstance, which is not visible in the code here.

You mention that this is in `-awakeFromNib:` — is it possible that this method runs twice? I had that a number of times confusing me, and it happens quite easily when e.g. you create a window controller as an IB object in MainMenu.xib, and then have said window controller load a NIB via `-[super initWithWindowNibName:]` in its own `-init:`. This calls `-awakeFromNib` once for each involved NIB. I had created some order of initialization issue in my case, which showed similar undetermined behavior to what you describe.

I moved the code to `-windowWillLoad` and `-windowDidLoad` method, which is per window and therefore doesn't have this problem.

Comment: A great big thank you, febeling. That appears to be it! I did indeed, stupidly leave an NSObject instance in a nib file by mistake. I've run it 10 times or more now and all seems fine! As an aside: reinstalling Xcode also seems to have fixed the project settings update issue, so maybe you had what I did, that is, Xcode 4.2 and 4.3 on the same machine. Spotlight on my machine appeared to be mixing the two version up so sometimes I was running 4.2.

Comment: Heh, that's great to hear! :) I'll check Xcode versions over here.